# Java JFrame layout

Tags: java, swing, layout

This is the problem, I have a class MainWindow that extends JFrame in one of the setup routines I set the layout of the class to a new CardLayout(). This all works fine but when I go to request the the layout from the JFrame and cast what it returns to a CardLayout I get errors because it is returning a BorderLayout. I think you get the picture from hear.

Please find some code below:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    initWindow();
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    CardLayout m = (CardLayout)super.getLayout();
    m.next(this);
}

private void initWindow()
{
    super.getContentPane().setLayout(_mainLayout);
    super.setTitle(_WINDOW_NAME);
    super.setSize(_DEFAULT_WINDOW_SIZE);
    super.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    super.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    super.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    super.setResizable(false);

    init_buttons_panel();
    super.add(_buttons_panel, "bpanel");
}
```

I see that the code is not perfect this is because I have been trying everything to trap the problem. Yes I realize casting like that is not good but this is just test code to prove the point. Oh and _mainLayout is you guessed it a CardLayout.

I have also read how to use card layout and my code does not do anything out of the ordinary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should not cast a layout like that, at least without making any verifications. You should use the `instanceof` keyword first, to check if it really is a CardLayout, to prevent the program from finishing abruptly.

Second, the problem is here:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    CardLayout m = (CardLayout)super.getContentPane().getLayout();
    m.next(this);
}
```

Basicly you were getting the layout of the JFrame, and not from the JFrame's content pane, which is the one you actually set to be a CardLayout.

Answer (score 1):

```
super.getContentPane().setLayout(_mainLayout);
```

The code you posted doesn't help us since we don't have all the information. We don't know what the variable _mainLayout refers to.

I suggest you start by reading the section from the Swing tutorial [How to Use Card Layout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for a working example and a better designed program. For one thing there is no reason to extend JFrame since you haven't added any functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The getLayout method of JFrame is inherited from Container and thus does not forward on the call to the JFrame's content pane. You could try using `super.getContentPane().getLayout()` instead of `super.getLayout()`.